# How to track unique visitors on my local web-server?

Tags: php, unique

I have local PHP web-server (internet is not available here). How could I track identify and track unique visitors? Believe, mac-address is not available to my web-server.

Comment: Use cookies....

Comment: unique visitors as in "distinct computers" or "distinct persons using same computer". Wich kind of network? Is dhcp dinamyc? You could just grab the IP of the client if the dhcp's lease is long enough

Comment: @LordNeo, distinct computers. This is Palapa Web Server running on my Android phone. Believe, I can not use just IPs - they will not be unique.

Comment: If your network is on the same dhcp server then two computers can't have the same IP address, otherwise they will collide.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access the storage mediums available to you on the web to distinguish users. You can store a flag saying `visited: true`.

You can store this flag at

- LocalStorage
- Session Storage
- Cookie Storage
- IndexedDB
- WebSQL

Devices you might be able to differentiate on IP. But same user can come from different IPs and this process happens in the backend